# Android multi-process application

Tags: android

I have been wondering 1 thing about running multi-process app on Android.

Say, I have a setup in the manifest file as follow..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.multiprocess">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MainService"
            android:process=":main" />
        <service
            android:name=".SubService"
            android:process=":sub" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

With this, when I start both services with `startService()` and I will see each process listing separately on system's "Running services" page. (See image below)

I would like to know how can I get both processes list under 1 name like Google Play services does? (see image below)

[image: Android multi-process application]

Comment: The Settings app probably has its own way of figuring out how to render each app.  It might even treat Google apps specially.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the response, I believe you are right about this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, they use `android:sharedUserId` for all of their processes. But in any case you can figured that out by extracting AndroidManifest.xml from Google Play *.apk file and analyze it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try to extract the manifest file from the APK for study purpose. However, I don't observe any special configuration in the manifest. By the way, `android:sharedUserId` can only be set at `<manifest>` level. I believe @DougStevenson was right about the "Settings" app thingy.